# Excel if <> #NA

Tags: excel

To begin with I've tried searching the forum and can't find what I'm looking.

I am trying to use the following formula:

```
=IF(C70<>"#NA",C70,IF(D70<>"#NA",D70,IF(E70<>"#NA",E70,IF(F70<>"#NA",F70,"No Value"))))
```

The formula is trying to combine 4 different columns with data in, only one of the cells would contain a value which is not #NA and I want to display that value in G70.

Example Data Set:

```
     C      D          E       F
70   #N/A   30245_3    #N/A #N/A
```

The value will return only if in Column C, if any other column, it will return #NA.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: See the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check below formula:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(C70)),C70,IF(NOT(ISERROR(D70)),D70,IF(NOT(ISERROR(E70)),E70,IF(NOT(ISERROR(F70)),F70,"No Value"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data set contains #N/A whereas you are using #NA in your function.

You can IFNA function for this. Or IFERROR as suggested by Jeeped.

```
=IFNA(C70,IFNA(D70,IFNA(E70,IFNA(F70,"#N/A"))))

=IFERROR(C70,IFERROR(D70,IFERROR(E70,IFERROR(F70,"#N/A"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using excel 2016 you can look at using the [IFNA function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFNA-function-6626c961-a569-42fc-a49d-79b4951fd461)

Otherwise you could use the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) as Jeeped suggested

Answer (score 0):

Is it important, whether the error is #NA or any error?

if it is unimportant, you could use ISERROR instead of C70<>"#NA", otherwise you must use ISERR AND/OR ISERROR 
N/A = ISERR = FALSE, ISERROR = TRUE

```
IF(NOT(ISERROR(C70)) ...
```